# Bash Script - compare string with variable spaces against regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Thanks for your time and helping me

I am trying to make a script that compares the grep output with the result that I expect.

grep output is:

```
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

Because spaces or tabs vary on each server, I am using regex for these spaces

```
[[:space:]]*
```

In theory it should match the regex variable but it doesn't work.

Anybody knows what could be the problem?

```
function find_string () {

    if [[ $cmd =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo match
    else
        echo fail
    fi
}
cmd=`stat /etc/crontab | grep root`
regex="^Access:[[:space:]]*(0600/-rw-------)[[:space:]]*Uid:[[:space:]]*([[:space:]]*0/[[:space:]]*root)[[:space:]]*Gid:[[:space:]]*([[:space:]]*0/[[:space:]]*root)$"
find_string "$cmd" "$regex"
```

Comment: Parentheses are regex metacharacters, so you need to escape them in the regex.

Comment: You can also use `0600/-rw-*` instead of `0600/-rw-------`.

Comment: Perhaps a more fruitful approach would be to pass a format string to `stat` to only extract the information you actually want, in a format you can easily pick apart if you need multiple fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected a number of issues in your script including escaping parentheses in your regex string.

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

function find_string {

    if [[ "$1" =~ $2 ]]; then
        echo "match"
    else
        echo "fail"
    fi
}

cmd=`stat /etc/crontab | grep root`

regex="^Access:[[:space:]]*\(0600/-rw-------\)[[:space:]]*Uid:[[:space:]]*\([[:space:]]*0/[[:space:]]*root\)[[:space:]]*Gid:[[:space:]]*\([[:space:]]*0/[[:space:]]*root\)$"

find_string "$cmd" "$regex"
```

Note - The operator `=~` performs a regular expression match of the string to its left with the extended regular expression on its right. The string should be quoted, but the extended regular expression should not be quoted.